# Proof of Szegö asymptotic theorem

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, asymptotics, power-series, exponential-sums

Consider the truncated exponential series
$$P_N(z) = \sum_{n= 0}^N \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

The zeros of this series have been studied by Szëgo and others (see e.g. [here](https://doi.org/10.2307/30037629)). He established an asymptotic for the unique real zero of $P_N$ (for odd $N$):
$$-r_N = \eta N +\alpha \log N + \beta + o(1)$$
where the constants can be made explicit.

I do not find any reference or source for this proof (Szebo's original paper of 1924, in German, is often cited in this respect).

Comment: I don't get it. In the paper you linked, it refers to page 81 of "Aufgaben und Lehrsiitze aus der Analysis, Erster Band", which I just downloaded (negbil$^{-1}$). The idea seems to be to get asymptotics for $$\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^{\eta N+\alpha\log N+\beta} e^x x^n dx,$$ which is what you want, by what the anti-derivative of $e^x x^n$ is.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some references in English:

MR0072206
Rosenbloom, P. C.
Distribution of zeros of polynomials. Lectures on functions of a complex variable, pp. 265–285. University of Michigan Press, Ann Arbor, Mich., 1955.

MR1113918 Carpenter, A. J.; Varga, R. S.; Waldvogel, J. Asymptotics for the zeros of the partial sums of ez. I.  Rocky Mountain J. Math. 21 (1991), no. 1, 99–121.

MR1071774 Varga, R. S.; Carpenter, A. J. Asymptotics for the zeros of the partial sums of ez. II. Computational methods and function theory (Valparaíso, 1989), 201–207, Lecture Notes in Math., 1435, Springer, Berlin, 1990.

T. Kriecherbauer, A. B. J. Kuijlaars, K. D. T.-R. McLaughlin and P. D.
Miller, Locating the zeros of partial sums of e
z with Riemann-Hilbert
methods, in “Integrable systems and random matrices”, 183–195. Contemp. Math. 458, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 2008.

MR3938020
Bergweiler, Walter and  Eremenko, Alexandre,
Quasiconformal surgery and linear differential equations.
J. Anal. Math. 137 (2019), no. 2, 751–812.

The last paper is on completely different subject, but Szego's theorem is proved in section 3 as an auxilliary result.